# C# System.Data.SQLite : Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: c#, sqlite, concurrency, sql-update

I have a .net winforms application which is using SQLite DB and I am using System.Data.SQLite dll.

This is how I load a Datatable:

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter;
            SQLiteCommandBuilder m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder;

            m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder = null;
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter = null;

            // Create fresh objects
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, Database.getInstance().connectionObj);
            m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter);
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
```

This data table has one primary key and no other constraints.
I set it as a data source for DataGridView and after all the edits, I update the DataTable like this:

```
    m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter.Update(table);
```

Occasionally, the updates fires an error and I don't know when, it stops throwing errors - probably after system restart ( not sure ). And then, the updates go fine until another situation where this update throws an error again. When the error occurs, it happens for all updates from then on even after application restart.

Error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.DBConcurrencyException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

I would appreciate any help or questions as this is quite a critical section of my project.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Based on suggestions, to ensure no other part of the program is editing the row, I loaded the DataTable, updated the row immediately and updated it as per the following code. And *I still got the error*. There is no other program running on my machine so the row is not updated by any other program except my application:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter;
            SQLiteCommandBuilder m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder;

            m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder = null;
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter = null;

            // Create fresh objects
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, Database.getInstance().connectionObj);
            m_readingsDataTableCommandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter);
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter.Fill(table);

            // Update immediately
            table.Rows[0]["RS485_ADDRESS"] = "400";
            m_readingsDataTableDataAdapter.Update(table); // - Still throws error

            return table;
```

Comment: This means that the row the data adapter and command expected to be there is no longer there, or it is there but it has some critical values that are different. The currency violation stems from the fact that when the data adapter originally retrieved data it makes two copies of it, on underlying and one public. When you later on try to save updates back into the database it first tries to verify that the row is still in the database, with the same values as it originally had. If it is, *then* it performs the update. Clearly here the row was not present or it had changed.

Comment: Meaning that while you're manipulating the row in one place, some other piece of code or some other program is simultaneously updating the same row in the database. When you later on try to update it the update command basically says "update this row in the database that originally had a balance of 45 and a last due date of today to this new balance", and the row is there, but it no longer has a balace of 45.

Comment: Other than explaining that, it is impossible for us to help you as it would require you to look at large portions of the program to find out why the row is changing unexpected. If you actually expect the row to change as explained above, then you cannot use this system of updating the table as this *will* cause problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative reply Lasse. That really helps. I will investigate further on that.

Comment: I did my investigation on this and based on the code that we have, I am sure the program is not updating "any" row from "anywhere" else. In fact, I loaded a table, changed a value in  a row and updated immediately. It still throws the exception. 
Kindly see my updated question with this information and code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that drove me nearly mad. I even debugged into System.Data.SQLite . My issue was caused by the dynamic typing of SQLite:
Dynamic typing means that the column type is just a hint for the type of the stored value but not an enforcement. Here is what happened in my application: An integer column contained an empty string. Fetching the data triggered an implicit conversion to the column type so the empty string was converted to zero. The DbDataAdapter used this zero value in the WHERE clause of an UPDATE or DELETE statement which failed miserably because the conversion of zero to a string is not an empty string. I changed the affected integer columns to contain NULL and everything is fine now.

The sad fact about that: It is not a bug in SQLite or ADO.NET . DbAdapter and DbCommandBuilder expect strong typing and SQLite doesn't provide that by design.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. You saved my day (maybe more!)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem, it seemed to appear in some cases and not others.  I have resolved it a different way.  Since this is primarily a data issue, it involves changing the update and delete statements. There may be cases where your code might need to be validated, I'm not referring to those cases, this is for when all else seem to be in order and "Concurrency Violation" persists. And a good starting place before you spend hours debugging is to address how the updates are handled.

Open the Data Set Designer.
Click on the Table Adapter.
In the properties, expand the UpdateCommand

Edit the SQL so the Where-Clause refers only to the primary-key.

Example:  Suppose the column EmployeeID is the primary-key in our table
Change to:

update .....  WHERE EmployeeID=@EmployeeID

By default it's usually constructed as:

update ... where ID=@ID AND col1=@col1 AND col2=@col2 AND col3=@col3

The where-clause is formed with all the columns to handle multi-user updates, to enforce an implicit concurrency.  So if one user has a copy of the record, and another user updates that version by the time the first user updates it, first user's version is not current. Otherwise, primary-keys should be used to refer to a specific record.

But, this is an update/delete policy decision that the development and database teams need to coordinate. For a single developer/dba in-one, have a little meeting with yourself. Don't take the Microsoft where-clause without your review and understanding and explicit implementation.  Need to specifically address what happens when 2 users have a copy of the same record, both from the application and database levels. Database "Transaction Isolation" Levels in SQL Server is a way to address it.  ADO, ADO.NET, OLE DB, ODBC all have isolation level settings.  [More on SQL Server Transactions and isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017)

In some cases multiple users are not involved, or the application is updating internally, concurrency is fully controlled, where-clause can be formed with the primary-key.

In my case, the update is done without a user involvement, so it makes sense to use the primary key. If you understand the reasoning and the cause of the behavior, it's a matter of adjusting to fit your environment.